# How to deal with feature vector of variable length?

Tags: machine-learning

Say you're trying to classify houses based on certain features:

- Total area
- Number of rooms
- Garage area

But not all houses have garages. But when they do, their total area makes for a very discriminating feature. What's a good approach to leverage the information contained in this feature?

Answer (score 5):

You could incorporate a zero/one dummy variable indicating whether there is a garage, as well as the cross-product of the garage area with the dummy (for houses with no garage, set the area to zero).

Comment: I don't see how the dummy variable changes anything if you're setting the garage areas to zero. The problem I see with setting the non-existent garage areas to 0 is that they will be viewed as similar to extremely small garages, which is inaccurate.

Comment: @ty4: This is where the dummy comes in. For example, if you were to fit a linear model, thanks to the dummy you'd get a different intercept for houses with and without garages. On second thoughts, you probably don't even need the cross-product.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to build your dataset with all the features and in most cases it is just fine to fill with zeroes those columns that are not available.

Using your example, it would be something like:

```
Total area  Number of rooms Garage area
100         2               0
300         2               5
125         1               1.5
```

Often, the learning algorithm that you chose would be powerful enough to use those zeroes to classify properly that entry. After all, absence of value it's still information for the algorithm. This just could become a problem if your data is skewed, but in that case you need to address the skewness anyway.

EDIT:

I just realize there were another answer with a comment of you being afraid to use zeroes, given the fact that could be confused with small garages. While I still don't see a problem with that (there should be enough difference between a small garage and zero), you can still use the same structure marking the non-existence area garage with a negative number ( let's say -1).

The solution indicated in the other answer is perfectly plausible too, having an extra feature indicating whether the house has garage or not would work fine (specially in decision tree based algorithms). I just prefer to keep the dimensionality of the data as low as possible, but at the end this is more a preference rather a technical decision.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to incorporate a zero indicator feature. That is, a feature which is 1 when the garage size is 0, and 0 for any other value.

Your feature vector will then be:
area | num_rooms | garage_size | garage_exists

Your machine learning algorithm will then be able to see this (non-linear) feature of garage size.